# Why should I throw an exception like throw ex?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, exception

I understand that `throw` preserves the **call stack** but `throw ex` does not.

Obviously, we find or we see many use cases for

```
    `throw` 

    `throw new exception("custom Message", ex)`
```

Now, what bugs me is that, If the `throw ex` **does not preserve the stack trace, why I should use that?**

Any practical scenarios where there is a reason to use the `throw ex` statement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're not interested in the exposing the stacktrace beneath this throw either because it's been logged elsewhere or isn't needed for the debug handling of the exception. I could even imagine some paranoia in exposing underying logic where it's not needed. (In which case, I'd expect to see a custom exception/custom throw and not a throw ex though)

More often than not though - it often seems to be because the programmer didn't know the side effects of throw ex.